# how to know the result of substraction of date

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I have a date like this `2017-07-25 09:30:49`, when I subtract `2017-07-25 10:30:00` and `2017-07-25 09:30:00`, I need a result like `1 Hours`.

I can't find correct search key for googling what I need.
Anyone know what should I search on google ? or someone knows some function about that?

PS. Mysql or Javascript

Comment: For JS: *the Date object*, *subtracting Dates*, *converting milliseconds to hours*, *concatenating strings*

Comment: This question has been answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020517/calculating-the-time-difference-in-an-php-mysql-javascript-system

Comment: You really didn't try to search very hard

Comment: @charlietfl man I tried for hours

Answer (score 1):

Try with date object in javascript
Like this

```
var d1 = new Date("2017-07-25 10:30:00"); 
var d2 = new Date("2017-07-25 09:30:49") 
var diff = Math.abs(d1-d2);  // difference in milliseconds
```

Then convert the milliseconds to hours

```
var hours = parseInt((diff/(1000*60*60))%24);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go through it
[Get the time difference between two datetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623783/get-the-time-difference-between-two-datetimes)

But the query is not clear do you want only the hour difference or you want the difference converted to hour format

Like what it will give if 2017-07-25 09:30:49  and 2017-07-26 10:30:00 ? 25 hour or 1 hour?

Comment: or you can also go through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020517/calculating-the-time-difference-in-an-php-mysql-javascript-system

Comment: 25 hours, so I could know

Answer (score 1):

here a code example of how to do it

```js
var date1 = new Date("2017-07-25 09:30:49"); 
var date2 = new Date("2017-07-25 10:30:00");

var datesum = new Date(date1 - date2);
var hours = datesum.getHours();
var minutes = datesum.getMinutes();
var seconds = datesum.getSeconds();

console.log(hours + " hour, " + minutes + " minutes, " + seconds + " seconds" )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dateString = "2017-07-25 09:30:49";
var dateString2= "2017-07-25 11:30:00";
var reggie = /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/;
var dateArray = reggie.exec(dateString); 
var dateArray2= reggie.exec(dateString2); 
var dateObject1= new Date(
(+dateArray[1]),
(+dateArray[2])-1, // Careful, month starts at 0!
(+dateArray[3]),
(+dateArray[4]),
(+dateArray[5]),
(+dateArray[6])
);
var dateObject2= new Date(
(+dateArray2[1]),
(+dateArray2[2])-1, // Careful, month starts at 0!
(+dateArray2[3]),
(+dateArray2[4]),
(+dateArray2[5]),
(+dateArray2[6])
);
var diff = Math.abs(dateObject2-dateObject1);  // difference in milliseconds
 var hours = parseInt((diff/(1000*60*60))%24);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below dateFormatter function :

```js
var d1 = new Date("2017-07-25 10:30:00"); 
var d2 = new Date("2017-07-25 09:30:00") 
var diff = Math.abs(d1-d2);
var d = dateFormatter(diff);
console.log(d);

function dateFormatter(t){
    var cd = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    var ch = 60 * 60 * 1000;
    var cm = 60*1000;
    var d = Math.floor(t / cd);
    var h = '0' + Math.floor( (t - d * cd) / ch);
    var m = '0' + Math.round( (t - d * cd - h * ch) / 60000);
    var s = '0' + Math.round((t - (d * cd) - (h * ch) - (m * cm))/1000);
    return d + " days, " + h.substr(-2) + " hours, " + m.substr(-2) + " minutes, " +s.substr(-2)+ " seconds";
}
```